# wp_get_object_terms() returns invalid taxonomy inside rest_api_init hook

Tags: rest-api

I have created a taxonomy called 'country' and I have created a function that hooks into `rest_api_init` inside which is `wp_get_object_terms($post-ID, 'country')`. For some reason `wp_get_object_terms` returns 'invalid taxonomy'. However, when I copy the function elsewhere, e.g. into a custom page template, it returns post country taxonomy terms fine.

Any help??? Here's my code for reference:

```
function myevents_get_post_items() {

    $args = array (
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'post_type'         => 'venue',
    );

    // query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 

        echo '<pre>';

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            $post_id = $post->ID;
            print_r(wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'country'));
        
        endwhile;

        echo '</pre>';
        
    endif;

}


function myevents_register_api_endpoints() {
  register_rest_route( 'myevents/v2', '/venue', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'myevents_get_post_items',
  ) );
}
 
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'myevents_register_api_endpoints' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue with the following post type and taxonomy registration code (which I put in the `functions.php` file of a child theme):

```php
add_action( 'init', function () {
    register_post_type( 'venue', [
        'public'       => true,
        'label'        => 'Venues',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    ] );

    register_taxonomy( 'country', 'venue', [
        'public'            => true,
        'label'             => 'Countries',
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
    ] );
} );
```

Then I used your code to register the custom REST API endpoint (note though, you should *always* set the [permission callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback) just as I did below):

```php
register_rest_route( 'myevents/v2', '/venue', array(
    'methods'             => 'GET',
    'callback'            => 'myevents_get_post_items',
    // always set this, but the value doesn't need to be __return_true
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
) );
```

And then when I visited `https://example.com/wp-json/myevents/v2/venue`, I did not get the "invalid taxonomy" error.

But I did notice an issue in your `myevents_get_post_items()` function — the `$post` variable is undefined.

Hence I used `$post_id = get_the_ID();` instead of `$post_id = $post->ID;`. (But you could instead add `global $post;` or `$post = get_post();` somewhere in your function, before you access the `$post`.)

So please fix that issue and ensure that your custom taxonomy is registered in the `init` hook. And note that the `wp_get_object_terms()` call worked for me, with or without setting the `show_in_rest` to a `true`.

Also, I guessed those `echo` and `print_r()` calls were just for testing, but still, keep in mind that your callback should not echo anything.